# My tabs are not working as they should

Tags: html, css, nav

I just finished writing my code for my navigation tabs using HTML5 and CSS3, but I'm having an issue! The tabs work perfectly in notepad, but when I put it in my website, it just doesn't work.

This is my CSS code:
    nav ul ul {
            display: none;
    }

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #D8D8D8  10%, #D0D0D0 90%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D8D8D8  10%, #D0D0D0 90%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D8D8D8  10%, #D0D0D0 90%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 10px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    font-family:arial;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 10px 40px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family:arial; font-weight:900;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
        }
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

The following is the HTML code I use to place them in the website:

```
<center><nav>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Arcade</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/arcade/action">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/arcade">Arcade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/puzzle">Puzzle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/vehicle">Vehicle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/violence">Violence</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/defense">Defense</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/pointnclick">Point N Click</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/rpg">RPG</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Watch</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/watch/tv">TV Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="/watch/movies">Movies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Extras</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/updates">Updates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav></center>
```

If I delete the Home tab, the Arcade tab takes its place and looks the same way. Any ideas?

My website that this is happening on is: http://gameshank.com/8-20-13/

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your site an additional link is inside your first li.

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

Also the center tag is deprecated. You should use:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

For block level elements.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! It worked great, to think it was something so silly as that!

Comment: If you find an answer acceptable you can click the check mark to the left of it to mark it as correct and show your question has been answered

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the whole Q&A when I ask. And a quick question, what did you mean the <a id="top"></a> was in the first li? I don't completely understand which li it is in.

Comment: In the code you posted here the first li is <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>. If you right click on the Home link and select inspect element the first li was <li><a id="top"></a><a href="/">Home</a></li>. It looks like you fixed it.